# Is human being a Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, artificial-intelligence

We may not have a determinate answer to this question. But is there any evidence for or against this question? Or is there any study on it?

Comment: Of course a living human being is not an abstract model of computation. So I think your question is really about the computational power of a human brain and a Turing machine.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question to ask, that possibly should be
rephrased as, "could a human being be simulated by a Turing Machine".
Other than the work in AI, I do not see studies bearing directly on
it. However there are studies on the relations between physics and
computation that have a bearing on the issue. See my answer. Some people seem to be scared by some questions. Does it mean they are good ones?

Comment: And, I forgot to say, there is actual research on the limits of
computability, both from an abstract point of view, and from a
physical point of view. See some references in
http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6644#6647 . It could
have a bearing on the question asked. But it is unlikely to bring
answers in any close future. At least one undisputable mathematician was
involved, Kurt Gödel, and his work on this is recognized in physics.

Comment: The question can also be interpreted as "can a human being act as a Turing machine" in which case the answer is: yes, for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is a dog an animal?" is different from "Is an animal a dog?".

I read your question as going only in one direction: can a human being
be simulated by a Turing machine?  It is not about human beings being
able to simulate a Turing machine, or "functioning" as one.

Essentially this is an open question, that depends on
Chuch-Turing thesis, and on issues in physics regarding the physical limitations to computation that are still open
(though some people dispute that, but history shows that some physicists
have been known to believe they had nearly all the answers, the rest being expected next Friday).  These
issues involve for example the nature of time, and the opposition
between a continuous and a discrete reality. Democritus (460-370 BCE)
still lives.

Some details can be found in the second part of [another answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/6644#6647) I gave.
There is a little bit more to it, but it is a first sketch.

Of course it could be that the answer to the OP's question is
positive, even though the more general issue of computability might
ultimately show that the Chuch-Turing limit could be overcome (I am not saying it can). But other
than AI research, and brain research, that is all we have for now, afaik.

Answer (score 6):

A Turing machine is a tuple consisting of an alphabet, a tape, some transition, etc.

I am not one of those. So no. A human being is not a Turing machine (or at least, I am not).

Comment: They all say that when they want to pass for one of us. But we are not
fooled. What is hiding under your hat anyway ?

Answer (score 4):

If you allow me an unbounded stack of paper to store the tape contents, I can obviously simulate a Turing machine, so a human being plus data storage is at least as powerful as a Turing machine. If you don't allow me to use paper, there seems to be a finite upper bound on how much data can be stored in my body, so I probably can't simulate a Turing machine.

As to whether a Turing machine can simulate a person, that's essentially the question of whether strong AIs exist, which is an open problem and a matter of much discussion among philosophers.

Comment: You'll also need unlimited time of life.

Comment: The point of the Turing machine is to model (a simplified form of) human computation, so yes, you can use external storage.